# Antd table to filter one input against multiple dataIndex?

Tags: react-redux, antd

I have an antd table which has a simple dataset. You can specify a dataIndex to perform filtering.
But what I need to do is to provide only one search field that will use two different dataIndex to search.

I.E:
In my data sample, name and lastname are two different properties.

```
{
  name: 'Ricardo',
  lastname: 'Buquet',
}
```

I want to have only one filter field called "Full Name"
where the user can input name or lastname and filter by any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by storing search input value (other filter and pagination parameters) in your state and filter your data accordingly( in redux or component) like the code below. 
If you share your source code i can provide a more specific answer.

```
handleSearchInputChange = (e) => {
    const { params } = this.state;
    params.search = e.target.value;
    this.setState({params});
};
handleSearch(){
    if(this.state.params.search !== ''){
        const { columns } = this.state;
        columns.forEach(column => {
            if (column.key === 'id'){
                column.filterIcon = <Icon
                    type="search"
                    style={{ color: '#108ee9' }}
                />;
            }
        });
        this.setState({columns});
    }
    this.props.listUsers(this.state.params);
};
```